# UISplitView not shown full screen when opened in portrait and in landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with 1 button (more to come). When i click a button uisplitview must open. The problem is that it opens very strange.
I made some screenshots that will clarify what is wrong.
Button not clicked in portrait:

[image]

Button clicked in portrait(notice yellow upper part):

[image]

Button not clicked in landscape:

[image]

Button clicked in landscape (notice right side):

[image]

Am i missing some settings that will remove that "anomalies"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SplitViewController is meant to be the root view controller. Apple discourages you from using it as a view controller other than the main view controller.

From the docs:

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create.

Comment: This is bad for me if this is true. Where did you find it in docs, i can't see it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009277-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3

Comment: Here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW2

Comment: Is this then a good substitute without such limitations? http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad